# AltGr remapped to Context Menu

Tags: keyboard

I have an xps13 8350 with an azerty French keyboard on Windows 10.

My <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key started to act like <kbd>ContextMenu</kbd> out of nowhere.
I was coding and all of a sudden I couldn't use [], etc. anymore. As far as I know, I didn't do anything specific.

I tried rebooting and go into advanced options and then command prompt, my keyboard was behaving as expected in there.

I don't use any remapping, no AHK, etc.

I tried using different keyboard mappings in the Windows settings with or without <kbd>AltGr</kbd> support, the behavior is the same on every mapping.
My guess is that I must have done something weird with <kbd>Fn</kbd> but I'm not sure how to undo it.

EDIT: I should probably mention that locking <kbd>Fn</kbd> or not doesn't do anything;

Comment: By any chances, did you have any open RDP connection?

Comment: Nope. Nothing of the sort, no virtual box, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling windows.